# Continue execution of ajax request after altering with ajax:beforeSend

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, ujs

Using the jquery_ujs to handle ajax forms in my rails application. I altered a form to be sent with remote: true, by callig a ajax:beforeSend event on it. I'll like to make it continue execution if it the action execution is confirmed as I use [sweetalert](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert)

```
$('.content>.fr span:last-of-type>a').on "ajax:beforeSend", (xhr, settings) ->
        swal
          title: "Are you sure?"
          text: "You will not be able to undo this!"
          type: "warning"
          showCancelButton: true
          confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55"
          confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
          closeOnConfirm: false
        , ->
          # should send the request here
          swal "Deleted!", "Department has been deleted.", "success"
          return
```

To view a complete version of it, it is on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bl4ckdu5t/fc495bae88ca4811e446).

Answer (score 0):

You should like this

```
$("body").on("click", "#element", function(e) {           
             swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Are you sure?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                closeOnConfirm: false },
                function(){
                   // ajax goes here
                }       
            );
        });
```

SweetAlert differs from javascript confirm, the script execution does not stop while waiting user input, so if the function in beforeSend does not return false the ajax continues proceeds on the request.

Comment: On my second rails project now and I never even tried ajax since I've been developing in rails. I only use the UJS ` remote: true`